# Ресурсы android проекта

Tags: android, android-studio

Добавляю картину в ресурсы проекта android studio в папку drawable но студиа не видит добавленные фалы ни в java коде, ни в XML. В классе "R" они тоже не отмечены.

В чем может быть проблема ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки после Rebuild

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как ты их добавляешь? Clean-R->Rebuild пробовал?А другие типы ресурсов так же игнорируются?

Comment: @jangorussia, сделал и выдало ошибки, я прикрепил их к вопросу! Но я не могу понять в чем проблема. Все имена ми так в нижнем регистре.

Comment: и переименовывать пробовал?

Comment: @jangorussia, пробывал. И слитно писал, проблема остается.

Comment: @jangorussia, пересобрал  проект и перестало видеть R.  И как теперь его вернуть ?

Comment: В таких случаях мне помогало уlалить проблемные ресурсы. Clean project. Build project.

Comment: @jangorussia, спасибо, ресурс вернулся .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас в имени файла `right _arrow.png` пробел. Пробелы в именах ресурсов запрещены.

Comment: я уже слитно написал! Но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Vitaliy  сделайте Build. Если не сработает - покажите текст новой ошибки

Answer (score 2):

right _arrow.png с пробелом. В логе четко указано на ошибку.

Comment: Переименовал, без пробелов, без подчеркиваний. Но проблема осталась.

Comment: @Vitaliy Какие новые ошибки в логах появились? Также, часто R отпадает из-за ошибок в XML.

Comment: удалил проблемные ресурсы и асе стало на места

Answer (score 0):

Помогло просто замена картинки на другую и пересборка проекта.